# UIProgressView - owning UIView not displayed and updating NSTimer firedvery late (up to 25 sec)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

While reading an audio file (which can be big), I want to display a progress view on a main view controller subview (it is an UIView).

I wrote a method for that in my UIViewController:

```
- (void) displayFileReadingView
{
        self.fileReadingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20., 100., 300., 120.)];
        self.readingProgress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20., 90., 200., 8.)];
        self.readingMessage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45., 10., 200., 20.)];
        ... elements parameter settings ...
        [fileReadingView addSubview:self.readingMessage];
        [fileReadingView addSubview:self.readingProgress];
        [self.view addSubview: self.fileReadingView];
}
```

In the `viewDidAppear` methods, after all last initializations, I read an audio file (using AVURLAsset) and analyse the data to plot it.

When `displayFileReadingView` is called from `viewDidLoad`, or `viewWillAppear`, the view is displayed correctly. When it is called from `viewDidAppear`, as a first line, it is not displayed until several seconds after the end of the `viewDidAppear` execution. This is my first question:

*• Why an UI method to allocate views, subviews and add them to the appropriate view, allow display or not depending of the calling method, since the displayFileReadingView method is not dependent of any initialization parameter from the main view managed by the owning UIViewController?*

Here is the second problem. My UIProgressView is supposed to be updated every second, using a NSTimer scheduled to call updateReadingProgress

```
- (void) updateReadingProgress {
            [self.readingProgress setProgress:myNewValue animated:YES];
            [self.fileReadingView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But unfortunately, the `NSTimer` is not fired in time. If the allocation (using either `ScheduledTimerWithTimerInterval`... or `TimerWithInterval`... + adding in main loop (all modes tested) is made normally, it is never fired. If I put the same allocation in a dispatch_main_async() (or dispatch_after...) the timer is fired many seconds after for the first time, sometimes up to 25 seconds.

The result, depending on my code choices explained here: sometimes the  view is not displayed, sometimes not. When it is, its `UIProgressView` subview is never updated, or updated dozen of seconds after all other calculations are done (after the owner view should be removed from display).

I also tried to replace `NSTimer` with `CADisplayLink` to fire `updateReadingProgress` method, using an "ordinary" call or "dispatched in main queue" included call, but in this `CADisplayLink` case it is never fired. Spent two days and nights in trying combinations, reading developer websites... no solution!

This is my second question:

*• How can I be sure that a method updating the UI get called periodically without giant delay (some .2 or .5 second delay is not a problem?*

[Using Xcode9 for iOS10 target, tested on Simulator and devices (iPhone/iPad)]

Comment: iOS is not preemptive and all UI updates occur on the main queue. If the main queue is busy then any UI updates (and timer events that need to be dispatched on the main queue) will be delayed until the main queue is free to process them. The first thing you need to ensure is that your time consuming task is running on a utility queue, not the main queue.

Comment: Thanks, Paulw. But how can I do that if a simple UiView does not display...

Comment: Once you stop hogging the main queue then all of the UI updates, timers etc will start working.  The main queue is a serial dispatch queue; it only does one thing at a time, so if it is busy performing calculations then anything else is queued until that work is over.

Comment: Thanks. I put all the hogging code in a NSOperationQueue, and everything is running smoothly.